# HTML radio button truncates all letter after space when assigning value

Tags: python, html, django

By my read of the code shown below, clicking Test 1 or Test 2 should return Test 1 or Test 2, whichever was clicked; however, instead Test is only returned. Essentially everything following the space is truncated in the value field. Why is this happening? Thanks for your input!

HTML

```
<div>
    <form action = '/test_out/' method = 'POST'> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for item in test_var  %}
            <input type = "radio" value = {{ item }} name = 'clicked'>
            {{item}}
            <br><br>
        {% endfor %}
     <input type = 'submit' text = 'Modify Hull'> 
    </form>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def test(response):
    return render(response, 'main/hull_view.html', {'test_var': ['Test 1','Test 2']})

def test_out(response):
    return HttpResponse(response.POST.get('clicked'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is due to not having value in quotes. Could you try putting quotes around value field
`<input type = "radio" value = "{{ item }}" name = 'clicked'>`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take a shower and try to wash the shame off of my body now...